# Variance between the same objects in different columns

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I've got a pivot table that contains Countries in Rows and few different types of revenue in columns, grouped by Scenarios. I've got 5 types of scenarios, and I need to show 2 of them at once for comparison.

It looks like this:

```
        ScenarioX           ScenarioY         
        Revenue1, Revenue2, Revenue1, Revenue2
Country1
Country2
```

The problem appears when I want to add a variance columns, that would calculate the difference between Revenue1(ScenarioX) and Revenue1(ScenarioY) etc.
I know how to use calculated fields, but this case is much harder, is it even possible?

I have tried to add a standard table right next to the pivot table, that takes the values directly from the pivot and calculates them. It works, but in this case i will need to hide and expand the table basic on the revenue type filter, which crashes the table.

```
        ScenarioX           ScenarioY           Variance
        Revenue1, Revenue2, Revenue1, Revenue2, Variance 1,  Variance2
Country1                                        Rev1X-Rev1Y, Rev2X-Rev2Y
Country2                                        Rev1X-Rev1Y, Rev2X-Rev2Y
```

What I need exactly is a hint, how to add the calculated fields, or other methods (through vba maybe?) to make the table look like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok found the solution finally, posting here, maybe it will help someone:

1. Duplicate the field in the pivot table "VALUES" area
   [optionally - change it's name to "Variance"]
2. Right click on the new field -> Value Field Setting -> Show Values As tab
3. In the Combo Box change the field to "Difference From"

In the Base Field in my case I had to select "Scenario", in Base Item - the scenario that
will be substracted from the main one.